# Who is the Guy Who Issues the Quests in Blackrock

Tags: hearthstone

So the Hearthstone Blackrock solo adventure is about ridding Blackrock of Ragnaros.

At least so you're told so by some guy with a staff, who is apparently the benefactor of your quest.

Who is that guy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's [Lord Victor Nefarius](http://www.wowwiki.com/Victor_Nefarius), the human form of the dragon [Nefarian (a.k.a. Blackwing)](http://www.wowwiki.com/Nefarian). His goal is to drive Ragnaros out of Blackrock to take control of it himself.